Play Console Closed Test App Cant Update At Play Store
I created a new version in the closed test of the mobile application that I will publish on Android with Play Console. When I try update this application on the phone, the update download is completed but an error occurs during the installation phase and the update does not occur. The update only occurs when the application is deleted and reinstalled, I do not want this to happen.
I tried solutions such as clearing the Google Play cache, restarting the phone, logging in to Google Play again, but I could not find a solution. The application code was written with Flutter. I am sure that the version in pubspec.yaml is correct and updated.

How can i fix this,i want to update without any reinstall at play store.
